# Prove that if $n = x^2 + y^2$ for some $n,x,y \in \mathbb Z$ then $n$ is even or $4 | (n-1)$

Tags: proof-writing, divisibility, integers

So I have a question which reads Prove that if $n = x^2 + y^2$ for some $n,x,y \in \mathbb Z$ then $n$ is even or $4\space |\space (n-1)$. I honestly have no idea where to start...

Comment: It might seem obvious (apologies), but a good starting place is literally "if $n$ is even, we are done.  So let's assume $n$ is odd."  From here, we note that if $n$ is odd, then either $4|(n-1)$ or $4|(n-3)$, or stated equivalently, $n \equiv 1 \text{ or } 3 \pmod{4}$.  So the question becomes: why can't we have $n \equiv 3 \pmod{4}$?

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

For any integer $a,$ $$a\equiv0,1,2,3\pmod4\implies a^2\equiv0,1$$

So, what are the possible values of $$x^2+y^2\pmod4$$

Comment: what do you mean by "(mod 4)"? Also whats the equal sign with 3 lines mean? Sorry this is new notation to me

Answer (score 0):

Note that $x^2\equiv 0$ (mod 4) or $x^2\equiv 1$ (mod 4).

Then, if $x$, $y$ are even or odd together, then $n$ is even. Otherwise, $n\equiv 1$ (mod 4).